# File path is too long to delete

Tags: windows, file, netbeans, path, server

I used NetBeans IDE to import a project on to my system (Win 98 Server 64bit) and it created a filepath too long to delete the files again. How do I remove the files?

Can't be removed using NetBeans, 
Deleting the folder containing the path structure doesn't work, 
Permanently remove files doesn't work.
Using rmdir \S \Q doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I succeded using 7-zip and `shift+del` the folder.

Comment: If you are just trying to delete a file, you can actually rename it from within the 7 zip app.  Open up 7 Zip and then navigate to the file as if you are going to open it to zip...simple rename the file from within the app and bam, all good!

Answer (score 5):

As I was front to this problem in windows 10, I share with you the solution which 100% work and that I found in this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete).

To delete a folder, use this command line

```
rimraf <dir>
```

rimraf is a Node.js package, so you will need to install Node.js which includes npm. Then you can run:

```
npm install -g rimraf
```

Then you can run rimraf from the command line.
I found this solution because npm itself was causing this problem due to the way it nests dependencies.

By the way, rimraf gets its name from the UNIX command rm -rf, which recursively deletes files and folders.

Answer (score 2):

Windows requires the file path be shorter than 255 characters. Try renaming some the containing directories until the path character length is less than 255. Then you should be able to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to delete such files using Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/) Just go to the folder and try to delete the file using

```
rm <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go inside the folders till the filepath is not too long to erase anymore

Comment: The filepath of the files being deleted is still the same no matter where I am in the path structure

Comment: @Krusing did you try? Did you get an error? This technique has worked for me, although it can be very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this (disclaimer: I'm the author): https://github.com/marceln/SuperDelete. It's a .NET command line app and I have builds for several runtime versions.

I've written it especially because there was no convenient way with minimal deps. You can check the releases page at https://github.com/marceln/SuperDelete/releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed node modules by running npm install on a boilerplate. While trying to delete those folders, windows does not allow us to delete them as path is too long to be able to handle.

:) :) After some of shallow research, I thought it would be right my own piece of code snippet to rename the folders from root to leaf so that it would throw any violation exception for this attempt as well.

Warning! Be careful about the folder path. This program will rename the folder name & its sub-folders with integers.

It works for me. Following is the code for c# project.

```
    public static int directoryCounterIndex = 0;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = @"<<Folder_You_Wish_To_Delete>>";
        RenameDirectories(dirPath);
    }

    private static void RenameDirectories(string dirPath)
    {
        directoryCounterIndex += 1;
        var newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + directoryCounterIndex.ToString();
        Directory.Move(dirPath, newPath);
        var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(newPath);
        foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
        {
            RenameDirectories(subDirectory);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 x64, you can [install Ubuntu bash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide).
Then you can goto to any directory using: `cd /mnt/<disk drive>/<path>` and delete it using: `rm -rf <path>` like if you were in Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Open 7zip File Manager, go to your folder in 7zip file manager, hold the Shift button down. Click the "Delete" button, either on your keyboard or in the 7zip File Manager toolbar; make sure you're still holding the Shift key down.Click the "OK" button; make sure you're still holding the Shift key down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a newish [open-source project](https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile) released by Microsoft, you can easily delete paths that are too long on network share using [WinFile](https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile) (which was introduced in WinXP). 
You just have to map the network share to a [drive letter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive). Sometimes you have to go "Back to the Future".

[image]

WinFile (compiled for Win10) available here https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile

To find many paths that are too long and automate a fix, I recommend [Path Too Long Auto Fixer](https://pathtoolongautofixer.blogspot.com/) - a free demo is available.

Answer (score 0):

Hack it with VSCode

1. Open the containing folder in VS Code.
2. then click on the file in left side file
   explorer of VsCode
3. then press del or shift+del.
4. confirm.

This is the most easy thing to do!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the file has like 20 folders deep. I moved up the file and deleted it gradually. E.g. if the file is in c:...20 layers of folder..\filename, you first mv c:...15 layers of folder\nextFolder to c:\ and delete it. Then mv c:...10 layers of folder to c:\ and delete it, and so on.